# SQL Server : numeric to varchar conversion with number format

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, casting, type-conversion

I see that unlike Oracle, number formatting doesn't exist in SQL Server. SO I'm trying to come with something equivalent.

Is

```
left(cast(expression as varchar(6)), 6)
```

a valid translation of the following Oracle numeric -> varchar conversion:

```
To_Char(expression, '990.00')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question tag indicates SQL Server 2008. But, if you are in fact using 2012 or higher (there are no SO tags for SQL Server 2012 or 2014), you have the [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function available to you.

Of course, if possible, you should do all output formatting in a presentation layer and not the database. It's generally not a database's job to present data. And you have a much larger array of options in a formal presentation layer.

Comment: FYI the tags are on SO - [SQL Server 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server-2012/info) [SQL Server 2014](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server-2014/info)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably also try with the CONVERT keyword

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

See the documentation here: [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

(works also for SQL Server 2008)